# Copying Linked List Recursively (Java)

Tags: java, recursion

End of a long night and I'm having trouble with copying a linked list recursively, I was able to do so with a simple iterative method, but I am having trouble with a stack overflow error when I try to set it up with recursion. Yet, this makes sense to me conceptually. Can anyone steer me in the right direction? This is what I have so far:

```
public LinkedList<E> createCopyRecursive(Node<E> aNode) {
    LinkedList<E> copyList = new LinkedList<E>();
    copyList.myStart = myStart;

    if (copyList.size() == 0) {
        aNode = myStart.getLink();
    }

    if (aNode.getLink() == null) {
        return copyList;
    }
    else {
        copyList.add(aNode.getValue());
        return createCopyRecursive(aNode.getLink());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `aNode.getLink()` yield the next node in the list? Also, are you sure that `copyList` should be placed within the method itself?

Comment: `copyList.size() == 0` this will always be true since `copyList` is always initialised

Comment: You should only create copylist at the bottom of the recursion when no node is found. and accumulate it when you go back up the stack.

Comment: Can you add the code for the Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be as simple as this:

```
private LinkedList<E> copyRecursive(final Node<E> node, final LinkedList<E> accumulator) {
                if (node == null) {
                    // all nodes traversed, return the result.
                    return accumulator;
                }
                // add current node to the copy list that is under construction.
                accumulator.add(node.getElement());
                // recursive call to copy the rest of the nodes to the copy list and return it when finished.
                return copyRecursive(node.getNext(), accumulator);
            }
```

First create an empty new linked list, which will contain the copy and then copy node by node into it recursively. You could also not pass an accumulator to it like this:

```
private LinkedList<E> copyRecursive(final Node<E> node) {
                    if (node == null) {
                        return new LinkedList<>();
                    }
                    final LinkedList<E> accumulator = copyRecursive(node.getNext());
                    accumulator.add(node.getElement());
                    return accumulator;
                }
```

But that will reverse the order of the nodes in the list.

Here is a fully working example with recursive copy and recursive reverse:

```
public class RecursiveCopyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        linkedList.add("first");
        linkedList.add("next");
        linkedList.add("last");
        System.out.println(linkedList);
        System.out.println(linkedList.copyRecursive());
        System.out.println(linkedList.reverse());
   }

private static class LinkedList<E> {

    private Node<E> first;

    public LinkedList() {
        first = null;
    }

    public LinkedList<E> copyRecursive() {
        return copyRecursive(first, new LinkedList<E>());
    }

    public LinkedList<E> reverse() {
        return reverse(first);
    }

    public void add(E element) {
        final Node<E> node = new Node<>(element);
        if (first == null) {
            first = node;
        } else {
            Node<E> current = first;
            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(node);
        }

    }

    private LinkedList<E> reverse(final Node<E> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return new LinkedList<>();
        }
        final LinkedList<E> accumulator = reverse(node.getNext());
        accumulator.add(node.getElement());
        return accumulator;
    }

    private LinkedList<E> copyRecursive(final Node<E> node, final LinkedList<E> accumulator) {
            if (node == null) {
                return accumulator;
            }
            accumulator.add(node.getElement());
            return copyRecursive(node.getNext(), accumulator);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            Node current = first;
            while (current != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(current.getElement().toString()).
                        append(" -> ");
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            stringBuilder.append(" _ ");
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        private static final class Node<E> {
            private final E element;
            private Node<E> next;

            public Node(final E element) {
                this.element = element;
            }

            public E getElement() {
                return element;
            }

            public void setNext(final Node<E> next) {
                this.next = next;
            }

            public Node<E> getNext() {
                return next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I gravitated towards something that looks very similar to this, but still having the same problem of it returning nothing because the first node is null by default.

Comment: Can you reflect the changes in your post?

Comment: If the first node of the list is null that would mean it is empty so a copy will result in an empty list as well.

Comment: Right, within the test driver that is a separate class file I have   newListIterative = theList.createCopyRecursive(null), but I need to figure out how to pass in the first value of the original linked list and do so recursively, do I NEED two methods?

Comment: Added a full working example. I don't have your implementation of the list so I created my own.

Comment: Also changed the implementation to use an accumulator list at the top, as @AmineAitErrami suggested, instead of making the accumulator at the bottom because that would create a reversed copy list.

Comment: Juru, while my implementation differs, I was able to get it, I had one minor error in the test driver as well as using the a second "helper" method incorrectly and you made me realize where I made the mistake, thank you so much for you help that was a very thorough answer.

Comment: Good to hear that :).

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new LinkedList every time you recurse into the method.

I suspect you want to instantiate it outside the method, pass it in and add to it each time through.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a recursive method to copy your linked list, I think you should first initialize copyList in another mehod that calls createCopyRecursive().

```
createCopy(Node<E> aNode) {
   LinkedList<E> copyList = new LinkedList<E>();
   createCopyRecursive(aNode, copyList) {
      ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing around whole linkedlist object you can just worry about head node.

Call to recursive method `copy()`

```
Node<Integer> copiedHead = copy(head);
```

Recursive method copy, accepts the head node and returns the copied head node.

```
private static Node<Integer> copy(Node<Integer> head) {
    if(head == null){
        return null;
    }   
    return new Node<>(head.getData(), copy(head.getNext()));            
}
```